# Passing a parameter within a URL Address Bar (for Sql Reports)

Tags: javascript, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, lightswitch-2013

Im struggling with passing the parameter on the URL Address bar...

heres what I have:

```
http://win-t8o9hquvjcf/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fDatasheetforOMManual&ProjectReference=65656
```

ProjectReference is the parameter wihin the Report Builder.. what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked it out, you have to use the `ReportServer` URL link, not the Reports on its own...

```
http://yourservername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fdatabasename%2freportname&rs:Command=Render&parameter=1
```

adding `&rs:Format=PDF` displays it as a PDF...

and for Lightswitch it works using the following:

```
var param1 = screen.tablename.param1
window.open("http://yourservername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fdatabasename%2freportname&rs:Command=Render&parameter=1" + param1 + "&rs:Format=PDF");
```